# CakePHP - HABTM - get results of joined database table

Tags: php, cakephp, many-to-many, cakephp-2.0, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am using CakePHP 2.0 and I have a many-to-many relationship betweens users and courses.
I have a database table `users`, `courses` and `courses_users`.

The problem is deleting courses which are already associated with a user. I won't delete them if there is an association to a user in `courses_users`.

So I wrote in my model `Course.php`

```
function beforeDelete() {
    if (??? == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

What I need is a database query written in CakePHP, so that I can determine if a course is not associated to any user (x == 0).
How can I do this? With a 1:n relationship I can write this

```
if($this->User->find("count", array("conditions" => array("course_id" => $this->id))) == 0)
```

but how can I do this in my n:m relationship?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the same as you would for hasMany, because one Course hasMany User and one User hasMany Course.

So try this (you won't need to create the UsersCourse or CoursesUser model)

In the Course model:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('User');
```

//in your method

```
if($this->CoursesUser->find("count", array("conditions" => array("course_id" => $this->id))) == 0);
```

Comment: I already tried this, but I get the error `Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object`, so `$this->CoursesUser` is not an object in my model.

Comment: Then try UsersCourse. I'm 100% sure that having a HABTM relation defined will create a link model called either CoursesUser or UsersCourse.

Comment: Ah, I found my error! I wrote `CourseUser` instead of `CoursesUser`. Thanks a lot, now I know how this works.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a model for courses_user?

Comment: Because I won't need it? All is done with the HABTM relationship, and it works fine, except the problem described. And I do not want to write raw SQL.